# How to broadcast assign numpy arrays along a certain axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can I "broadcast"-assign a matrix with a column? I.e., I want all the first row to be assigned the first entry in that column, and all the second row with the second entry in that column, and so on.

Example

```py
s = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
"""
s
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
"""
s[[0, 1], 1:] = np.array([1, 2])
```

which throws:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-606ac1668601>", line 1, in <module>
    s[[0, 1], 1:] = np.array([1, 2])
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,4)
```

Is there a way to do this in a broadcasting manner?

Comment: s[[0,1],1:]=np.array([3,4,5,6]) assign values like [3,4,5,6] because you assigned values start from first position.

Comment: To put something in a (2,4) space, it needs to be (2,4), (2,1), (1,4) or (4,).  The key is that a new dimension is only added automatically at the front.  This rule avoids ambiguities.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah I latter realised that. So Wen-Ben's `[:, None]` trick is necessary for numpy to correctly infer the dimensions.

Comment: Right the None converts the (2,) to (2,1) explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
s[[0,1],1:]=np.array([1, 2])[:,None]#numpy broadcast here 
s
Out[1169]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 5,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Comment: Thanks. So in effect, we still need to "span" the value to be assigned into a "full" form.

Comment: @Vim yep I think so